# How to test guest user in devise rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I want to use Devise in my App and i need guest user. I try to use this example - 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user

Now, i want write some rspec tests for user to describe the behavior when user becomes a member (this is logging_in action in application controller).

So, my test now is like this:

```
post :create_guest_user
guest_user = User.find(session[:guest_user_id])
sign_in(guest_user)

guest_user_id = guest_user.id

# Guest user create resume
post = guest_user.posts.build(:title => 'test of guest user')
post.save.should be_true
guest_user.posts.count.should == 1

# Guest user become a member
```

I don`t know, how to do '#Guest user become a member' section, i want to chek that new user will be creating after registration and all posts will be belong to him. In application controller i have

```
def logging_in    
guest_user.posts.each do |post|
  post.user = current_user
  post.save
end
end
```

How i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't `sign_in` with guest user. Actually I don't now why, maybe because it's not valid. Anyway to login as guest you need to add this to `ControllerMacros`:

```
module ControllerMacros
  # ...
  def login_guest(guest = false)
    guest ||= FactoryGirl.create(:guest_user)
    @request.env['warden'] = @warden
    @request.session[:guest_user_id] = guest.id
  end
end
```

And factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    ...
  end

  factory :guest_user, class: 'User' do
    sequence(:email)  { Faker::Internet.email }
    role              :guest
    to_create         { |instance| instance.save(validate: false) }
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
describe PagesController, type: :controller do
  context '#index' do
    before do
      login_guest
      get :index
    end

    it { expect(response).to have_http_status(:success) }
    it { expect(response).to render_template('pages/index') }
  end
end
```